# Is build error and compile error are same in c#?

Tags: c#

I studied about compile time error and run time error, but I don't know what is meant by build error.

Please let me know whether build error and compile error are same in C#?

Comment: Yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: Most of the times they are the same thing, but sometimes building is a bigger process. Compilation can be done with only the source code, but building include other things like resources, etc.

Comment: `I don't know what is meant by build error.` Where did you read about build error?

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not the same - *building* includes *compiling* but they are separate processes.

For example, you can have a problem when the build process cannot even download sources that would have been compiled.

Another example is a failed automatic test.

Comment: Would these be errors received in a build script?

Comment: It really depends on what the build script does and how it does it, but generally you can say yes, it would. On the other hand the build a script can be a part of another build script, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen an actual reference to such thing as a "build error" but I use that term when an error is received while compiling. I would say **"build errors" is a synonym for compile time errors.**

**UPDATED**

@tymtam has a good point in that build errors could be part of a build script. So I guess it depends on the context of when the term is used.